UICollectionView Crash: Expected dequeued view to be returned - Need Help Fixing Cell Reuse Issue
I'm facing a recurring crash in my iOS app with a UICollectionView. The crash message is as follows:
Error Message:
Thread 1: "Expected dequeued view to be returned to the collection view in preparation for display. When the collection view's data source is asked to provide a view for a given index path, ensure that a single view is dequeued and returned to the collection view. Avoid dequeuing views without a request from the collection view. For retrieving an existing view in the collection view, use -[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:] or -[UICollectionView supplementaryViewForElementKind:atIndexPath:]."
Background and Setup:
I am working on a project that involves a UICollectionView that displays news items. I am using a custom UICollectionViewCell (NewsCollectionViewCell) to represent each item. The UICollectionView has been registered properly, and I am using a standard implementation for dequeuing and configuring cells.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
Code: UICollectionView Cell Setup
class NewsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseId = "NewsCollectionViewCell"

    private let imageNews: UIImageView = { ... }()
    private let dateNews: UILabel = { ... }()
    private let nameNews: UILabel = { ... }()
    private let descriptionNews: UILabel = { ... }()
    private let readMoreLabel: UILabel = { ... }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageNews.image = nil
        dateNews.text = ""
        nameNews.text = ""
        descriptionNews.text = ""
    }

    func fill(with news: News) {
        // Populate the cell with data
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        // SnapKit constraints for layout
    }
}

Code: Collection View Setup and Cell Configuration
extension NewsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NewsCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as? NewsCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("Failed to dequeue NewsCollectionViewCell")
        }

        cell.fill(with: news[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
}

What I've Tried So Far:
Checked Reuse Identifier: The reuse identifier for NewsCollectionViewCell is correctly set and consistent everywhere.
Registered Cell Class: The cell is registered in setupCollectionView(), as shown below:
private func setupCollectionView() {
    newsCollectionView.delegate = self
    newsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    newsCollectionView.register(NewsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NewsCollectionViewCell.reuseId)
}

Avoided Manual Reuse: I've ensured that I'm not manually managing or holding references to dequeued cells.
prepareForReuse: Implemented prepareForReuse in NewsCollectionViewCell to reset all properties.
Tested on Different Devices and iOS Versions: The issue persists across different devices and simulators.
The Problem:
The crash occurs inconsistently, usually when scrolling rapidly through the collection view or after multiple reloads. The error message points to an issue with the cell reuse mechanism. Specifically, it suggests that the cell being dequeued might not be returned correctly, or that multiple dequeuing actions might be occurring simultaneously.
Questions:
Why does the error still persist even though I'm following the standard dequeuing approach?
Could there be an issue with my custom cell class (NewsCollectionViewCell) or how it's being reused?
Is there a better way to handle the scenario where dequeuing fails, rather than using a fatalError or creating a new cell instance?
Is it possible that the problem arises from using SnapKit for layout? Should I switch to another approach for setting constraints?
I'm running out of ideas on what could be causing this crash. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Start by setting an exception breakpoint to see which line is triggering the exception.

Also the guard let in cellForItemAt  is fairly pointless. Just use a forced cast as!

Could the code of func fill(with news: News) be an issue due to multiple "asynchrone" code? You don't use decoration view?
